# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.localSupportedSignAlgs from class sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker

Tags: java, ssl, google-cloud-sql

Still trying to deploy and get my server running .. As my Cloud SQL database is getting initialized I am getting the following exception:

```
[main] ERROR com.mz.server.BootstrappingServerConfig - Error trying to migrate SQL scripts ..
at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:56)
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1006)
    at com.mz.database.SqlDatabaseBootstrapper.executeMigration(SqlDatabaseBootstrapper.java:60)
    at com.mz.server.BootstrappingServerConfig.contextInitialized(BootstrappingServerConfig.java:46)
    ...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.localSupportedSignAlgs from class sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:963)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.localSupportedSignAlgs from class sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:285)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    ...
```

I am not sure what information I should deliver here - this would be my **app.yaml**:

```
runtime: java
vm: true

runtime_config:
  jdk: openjdk8
  server: jetty9

env_variables:
  'ALPN_ENABLE': 'true'   # OPTIONAL

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: mahlzeit-test:us-central1:mahlzeit-life-cloudsql-prod

health_check:
  enable_health_check: false
```

This is how I am configuring my `DataSource` in my Spring Application Context:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://google/mz_db?cloudSqlInstance=mz-test:us-central1:mz-life-cloudsql-prod&amp;socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

The compute instances which are accessing the Cloud SQL instances are in the same project.

Why am I getting

> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.localSupportedSignAlgs from class sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker

and how can I fix this?

---

Running `mvn dependency:list`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building mz-web-server 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:list (default-cli) @ mz-web-server ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.39:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-6:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:jar:1.21.0:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO]    com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:jar:1.21.0:compile
[INFO]    aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    com.paypal.sdk:rest-api-sdk:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.3.4:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO]    org.mindrot:jbcrypt:jar:0.3m:compile
[INFO]    com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO]    org.jooq:jooq-meta:jar:3.7.2:compile
[INFO]    commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.4:compile
[INFO]    org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:jar:3.7.2:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.3.2:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.3.4:compile
[INFO]    org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO]    commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO]    org.json:json:jar:20140107:compile
[INFO]    com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet:jar:2.8.0-beta1:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    com.mz:mz-data-model:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:jar:17.0:compile
[INFO]    commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    com.google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.15:compile
[INFO]    com.mz:mz-web-client:war:0.1-SNAPSHOT:runtime
[INFO]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO]    com.google.maps:google-maps-services:jar:0.1.14:compile
[INFO]    com.mz:mz-web-shared:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:jar:1.9.38:test
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO]    commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[INFO]    com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:jar:1.9.38:test
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    com.google.api-client:google-api-client:jar:1.21.0:compile
[INFO]    com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.9.38:compile
[INFO]    com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO]    com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.jooq:jooq:jar:3.7.2:compile
[INFO]    junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO]    classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    com.google.apis:google-api-services-sqladmin:jar:v1beta4-rev19-1.21.0:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO]    com.maxmind.geoip:geoip-api:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO]    com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO]    net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.10.1:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO]    org.jooq:jooq-codegen:jar:3.7.2:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:jar:2.7.5:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO]    org.flywaydb:flyway-core:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO]    com.sendgrid:smtpapi-java:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO]    com.google.http-client:google-http-client:jar:1.21.0:compile
[INFO]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO]    backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO]    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    com.sendgrid:sendgrid-java:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.730 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-06T09:27:35+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/226M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What JRE are you using? This seems to be a problem in the JRE code.

Comment: @Vadim My server is running Java 8

Comment: If you run "mvn dependency:list", do you see a "apln" dependency? If so, what version do you see? According to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues/122, there might be a compatibility issue between older version of the apln library and newer JRE versions.

Comment: @Vadim I added the result of `mvn dependeny:list` but there is nothing that is named `apln`. Is that good? ^^

Comment: `ALPN`, not `apln`. I see you have "'ALPN_ENABLE': 'true' ", I don't know what that exactly is but it would hint to that direction.

Comment: @eis sorry, was a typo but there is also no `ALPN` in the list. I have that `ALPN_ENABLE:true` from the documentation and didn't remove it. Appeas that this is an extension for the SSL protocol so I guess this might be the reason - I am enabling it but I don't include the dependency. I'll have to try that out.

Comment: IIRC dependency:list only lists the first-level dependencies, not the transitive ones. You might try `mvn dependency:tree` as well to get also transitive ones.

Comment: @eis Thanks for the hint! It's also not in the tree but I think that this must be the error. If `ALPN_ENABLED` is `true` then jetty will try to use it. This library appears to optimize HTTPS connections. Since I followed just a basic example I didn't think about what this actually means. I will try deploying with the APLN dependency added and then let you know if it worked :)

Comment: @eis It seems to work now! I'm getting another exception that my database does not exist which means I finally have a connection :) Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Vadim Thanks to you too! Since you're the Google SQL guy - do you want to provide an answer here for others to see? :)

Comment: @displayname as you actually worked it out and have the best details about the problem and the solution, go ahead and add the answer yourself :)

Comment: @eis Alright, I'm going to do that as soon as I'm back from work :) Thanks again for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was

```
env_variables:
  'ALPN_ENABLE': 'true'   # OPTIONAL
```

which I simply used from a tutorial without thinking about what that is/means.

ALPN is a library which appears to optimize HTTPS requests. I tried to add the library to my dependencies **which did not work**. Maybe I got the wrong version or something like that. However, at the moment this is no requirement for me.

To solve the issue I simply removed this variable. Setting it to `'false'` should also do it.